# Why .mkv, .flv, .ogv video file is not playing in safari?

Tags: video, safari, html5-video

I am using cloudinary for uploading the videos.

While trying to play the video,
I am using HTML video tag

```
<video controls playsInline>
    <source src={videoLink} />
</video>
```

**Its working fine in google chrome and other browsers. But its not playing .mkv, .flv, .ogv video files  in safari(15.4)**

Comment: Different browsers support different formats. You have to check before you use that format. Stay with MP4 files for playback in most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari doesn't support MKV's natively so you'd have to convert your video before playback by using a transformation.

Doing that with the video you've provided results in an error
In general, to help debug Cloudinary URLs, the response includes an x-cld-error header, and looking at the URL you've shared, I see the header comes back with:

```
Video is too large to process synchronously, please use an eager transformation with eager_async=true to resolve
```

There is an online (synchronous) video transformation limit(40MB for free plans and 100 MB for paid ones), which means that for videos larger than the limit you'll need to [perform the video transformations eagerly](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_videos#eager_video_transformations).

Eager transformations can be set upon upload or by updating your current resources using [the explicit API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#explicit).

Please take a look and see if that resolves the issue for you, and if you have any additional questions or need any guidance, just let me know.

Here is a sample code that I used,

```
 const upload = v2.uploader.explicit(
            public_id,
            {
                type: 'upload',
                resource_type: 'video',
                eager_async: true,
                eager: [
                    {
                        fetch_format: 'mp4',
                    },
                ],
                eager_notification_url: your_notification_url,
            },
            (error, result) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                resolve(result);                 
            },
        );
```